# X11 won't open a window

Tags: c++, x11

I am trying to open an X11 window, print out one pixel, and then later add code to make Terminate() return true. But it won't make a window. Here is my code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <iostream>

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

bool Termination() {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    Display *dspl = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!dspl) return 1;

    int screenNumber = DefaultScreen(dspl);
    unsigned long white = WhitePixel(dspl, screenNumber);
    unsigned long black = BlackPixel(dspl, screenNumber);

    Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dspl, DefaultRootWindow(dspl), 50, 50, 1280, 720, 0, black, white);
    XSetStandardProperties(dspl, win, "Lel", "Gaem", None, NULL, 0, NULL);

    GC gc = XCreateGC(dspl, win, 0,0);
    XSetBackground(dspl, gc, black);
    XSetForeground(dspl, gc, white);
    XClearWindow(dspl, win);
    XMapRaised(dspl, win);

    XDrawPoint(dspl, win, gc, x, y);

    while (Termination())
    {
    }

    XFreeGC(dspl, gc);
    XDestroyWindow(dspl, win);
    XCloseDisplay(dspl);
    printf("Job's done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What's keeping X11 from making my window appear?

Comment: X11 long time since I have done any of that. :-)

Comment: You forgot to flush the output? XFlush? And why are you using xlib, instead of xcb?

Answer (score 0):

add this before the while

```
  XMapWindow(dspl, win);
  XInternAtom(dspl, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question that the OP probably doesn't care about anymore but I was surprised it didn't have more answers, and maybe this can help someone else.

Although Andrew Nic's solution works incidentally, the real reason your original code didn't open a window is because Xlib both:

- A) queues requests into batches (similar to Nagle's algorithm), and
- B) is single-threaded

At the lowest level, Xlib is a just a library which converts your Xlib calls into network packets and enqueues them to it's internal tx queue. Since it doesn't have a separate thread running that queue, by just spinlocking in the while loop, Xlib never gets control again and so never has a chance to flush it's outgoing request queue, and the server never hears your CreateWindow request.

What you're *expected* to do is to have followed a pattern like this:

```
    while (Termination())
    {
        XEvent evt;
        XNextEvent(dspl, &evt);
    }
```

The XNextEvent will let Xlib know you're done for now and implicitly flush any pending requests. Alternatively you can technically get it to work as is by just explicitly telling Xlib to transmit it's queue first:

```
    XFlush(dspl);
    while (Termination())
    {
    }
```

...although note that it's generally ill-advised in any program to just spin like that without at least adding a short usleep() or poll() (e.g. "usleep(10 * 1000);" inside the loop). The kernel will eventually step in and pre-empt your process to keep other tasks going, but one core of CPU usage will go to 100%. Anyway as your program gets more complicated, you'll probably quite soon want to be running the event loop anyway. Xlib assumes that your program will be built around such an event loop, which is why the original code doesn't work as expected.

An exception to this is calls which return some sort of information from the X-server (or again at network level, what they really do is send a packet and block until receiving a reply from the server) -- those also force Xlib to do an implicit flush/sync since the server will obviously need to be "caught up" to the latest request in order to send the reply your program is waiting for. InternAtom is one such request which is why Andrew Nic's solution incidentally fixes the issue (note that the WM_DELETE_WINDOW atom that was looked up is never actually used, so it does nothing else and might as well have just been an XFlush() since this side-effect is the only effect).

- Note that calls such as XCreateWindow might seem to count since they return a "Window" (which is actually just a typedef'd uint32_t "resource ID" known as a xid at the raw protocol level) -- but those kinds of requests actually *don't* require a reply, and thus don't force a flush, because resource IDs are actually allocated *client-side* in X11 from a range given to your program by the server on connect; the Xlib library handles the details of finding a free xid for you, but Xlib actually knew what window ID it would be returning to you before even sending the request).

Note also that although drawing the pixel before the loop does work in many modern DE's (due to compositor), to be reliable, you are actually supposed to wait until you receive an Expose event before drawing to the window. At minimum, by not *re*-drawing on Expose, your pixel may disappear if the window is covered and uncovered (or iconified/restored).

Source: I'm familiar with the X11 protocol from developing a library which talks to X over raw TCP sockets, and am fairly familiar with the Xlib source code.